# Check if a VirtualAddress was returned by VirtualAlloc

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-management

I was wondering if it's possible to determine if a virtual address (pointer) belongs to a previous `VirtualAlloc` call or not (if possible without writing to the page). Since `VirtualFree` can automatically set the `dwSize` value if you use it with `MEM_RELEASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this or I don't understand the question?

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
void* p = NULL;
VirtualQuery(p, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
BOOL bWasUsed = (mbi.State==MEM_FREE)? FALSE: TRUE;
```